# Change background color of batch of similar image

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, transparency, batch-processing

Is there any way to change the background color of a batch of photos? 
All photos have the same dimensions and background

I have around 100 of these images with transparent background
[image]

[image]

These images are for a TFT display and the display UI editor does not support transparent images. It will convert the transparent part to white

[image]

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, Girish! Your question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25208116/imagemagick-how-to-change-transparent-background-to-a-color) (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467523/how-to-change-picture-background-color-using-imagemagick)). I suggest you to use [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org) for such a task.

Comment: Yes. It could be done in Photoshop by recording an Action and then applying it to a bunch images using File > Automate > Batch.

Answer (score 1):

**use Photoshop**

- open the first image
- record a new action
- add a new layer
- reorder the new layer to be the first layer from bottom
- change Foreground Color to white
- select the Palnt Bucket Tool
- and click on the image to make the new added layer white
- save the file
- stop the action recording
- click file > Automate > Batch
- in play section select you action
- in source select the folder that contain the images
- Check action save as commands
- click okay and Photoshop will do the work for you